# How to extend a protocol adding a computed static var

Tags: swift

I'd like to extend the CaseIterable protocol so that all CaseIterable enums have a `random` static var that returns a random case. This is the code I've tried

```
public extension CaseIterable {
    static var random<T: CaseIterable>: T {
        let allCases = self.allCases
        return allCases[Int.random(n: allCases.count)]
    }
}
```

But this fails to compile. Is there a way to achieve this using a static var? Or if not, how would I write the equivalent static func?

ps
Int.random extension for anyone playing along at home:

```
public extension Int {
    static func random(n: Int) -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(n)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can NOT create a generic type on a computed property. There is no need to randomize an index. You can use `Collection`'s randomElement method to return a random case and return `Self`:

```
public extension CaseIterable {
    static var random: Self { allCases.randomElement()! }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
enum Test: String, CaseIterable {
    case a, b, c, d, e
}

let test: Test = .random  // d
```

---

If you would like to return a random value you can constrain `Self` to `RawRepresentable` and return `RawValue`:

```
public extension CaseIterable where Self: RawRepresentable {
    static var randomValue: RawValue { allCases.randomElement()!.rawValue }
}
```

---

```
enum Test: String, CaseIterable {
    case a, b, c, d, e
}
```

---

```
let test = Test.randomValue   // "c"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use `randomElement` directly in the `CaseIterable` extension:

```
public extension CaseIterable {
    static var random: Self {
        allCases.randomElement()!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers are correct about how to fix it, but the why is probably as useful to understand. This is not doing what you think:

```
public extension CaseIterable {
    static var random<T: CaseIterable>: T {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This defines a property, `random`, which will return a value of type `T`, which is any type selected *by the caller* that conforms to CaseIterable. For example, according to this definition, I can make the following call:

```
let direction: LayoutDirection = Axis.random
```

And in this case, `Axis` promises that it will return a `LayoutDirection`, because that's what the caller has passed as `T`. Clearly this isn't what you want. You mean, every CaseIterable can return a random value of its *own* type, and as the other answer show, you do that with `static var random: Self`.

Generic type parameters (like `T` in this case) are parameters. They're passed by the caller, not chosen by the implementer.